# I am getting this error NSURLErrorDomain error -999

Tags: xcode, facebook, ios-simulator, iphone

I have authenticated my user with fb-connect in my application then when user click somewhere i open a facebook app URL in webview but before it get opened I get an error saying "The operation could not be completed. NSURLErrorDomain error -999"

Any idea?

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to "Foundation Constants Reference", error code -999 means "NSURLErrorCancelled".

Description:

> Returned when an asynchronous load is
>   canceled. A Web Kit framework delegate
>   will receive this error when it
>   performs a cancel operation on a
>   loading resource. Note that an
>   NSURLConnection or NSURLDownload
>   delegate will not receive this error
>   if the download is canceled. Available
>   in iOS 2.0 and later. Declared in
>   NSURLError.h.